# How to embed data in an application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cross-platform, wxwidgets, cross-compiling

I want to make an application, but the application will be using icons (bitmaps) for some of the menu buttons and other stuff. I want to keep my application as one simple, single standalone exe file which means I will somehow have to embed all of the icons into the application (EXE on windows) so I can load the bitmaps without having any external files.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Just some other info:
I'm using wxWidgets, currently with MSVC and I would prefer a method that works cross compiler/cross platform if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You could used the `XPM` format for your bitmaps, as it's easy to embed in your code (which of course is going to be in the exe, right where you want it;-).  As [the docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxbitmapoverview.html) say,

> All wxWidgets platforms support XPMs
>   for small bitmaps and icons. You may
>   include the XPM inline as below, since
>   it's C code, or you can load it at
>   run-time

(the "as below" being a `#include` directive) -- so, you would be perfectly cross-compiler and cross-platform by adopting this approach with the "include" option.

For more info about the `XPM` format, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap).  It's easy to find converters to XPM from other popular formats, of course.

Comment: @Brad, only transparency as an on/off option, I believe -- not the full, nuanced translucency offered by actual "alpha channels".

Answer (score 1):

Windows does have resource files.You could use that. Alternatively you could write a small utility that will convert your binary icon into a C constant array

eg:

```
const unsigned int my_icon[] = {0x12345678, 0x87654321, .... };
```

This could easily be done in perl and you can then access the icon with the variable my_icon.

Answer (score 0):

Cause Linux has no platform solution for this you will have to create your own system anyway. So i would recommand against platform specific ways to add resources on windows and macosx.

You can use reswrap which comes with the [FOX GUI Toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) is a simple tool to convert any binary file into c char literals. If you compile with msvc you will soon find that large files with lot of large strings are poison for the compiler. I added about 900 icons for my project and it killed the compiler.

I currently work with a solution where i simply copy a binary archive at the end of the executable. Every platform today can give you the executable path and neither ELF, EXE or Mach-O files care if additional data is added at the end of an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

We use this technique in our projects:

1. Use `optipng ./image.png` to optimize your png file.
2. Convert your binary image data to a text using `png2wx` Perl script.
3. Embed your image into the source code this way:

   ```
   {
       wxMemoryInputStream sm("\211PNG\r\n\032\n\000\000....", 116);
       m_bitmap = wxBitmap( wxImage(sm) );
   }
   ```

Do not forget to add the support for the PNG format in your `wxApp::OnInit()` function:

```
wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);
```

[Here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Embedding_PNG_Images) is the link to original tutorial.

Hope this will help!